# Alarm Manager isn't working on Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my Project  my class extending `Fragment`. I can't understand why `AlarmManager` doesn't work. In logcat it shows `NullPointerException`:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AppService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 10*1000, pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Please show the logcat messages. And, where in the code, it stopped?

Comment: I don't know "AppService.class" is a valid class name. Did you import the correct package?

Comment: AppService.class is the class which extends the android.app.Service superclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good link is @ [Scheduling Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set). Code snippet from the webpage:

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
        60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
```

Notice it uses Context.ALARM_SERVICE for getSystemService method.

Comment: 03-22 06:36:08.235: W/System.err(24186): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 06:36:08.255: W/System.err(24186):  at com.call.forward.home.Home$2.onClick(Home.java:335)
03-22 06:36:08.255: W/System.err(24186):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
03-22 06:36:08.255: W/System.err(24186):  at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:139)
03-22 06:36:08.255: W/System.err(24186):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18395)

Comment: The code crashed from your code at Home.java:335, line 335. Where is that code? please post it. Also pls post the logcat message on your posted question instead, so that all can see it and review.